# Using the && / AND operator for an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

This code checks if `$value` (array) is set in the database as `1`. The foreach loop saves all the founding matches into the array `$products`. Now I have all the fields in the database which have the value `1` but that's not really what I want, because if the field 'dog' equals `1` and the field 'cat' equals `NULL`, I still have the value of 'dog' in my array. It only should get to the array when BOTH equal 1.

For simple variables you can use the `&&` or `AND` operator to check if all keys have the same value but how do I do this with an array?

```
$products = array();
foreach($_POST['selected_checkboxes'] as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
    if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM produkte WHERE `$value` = 1")){
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            if (!in_array($row->name, $products)) {
                array_push( $products, array('name'=>$row->name, 'image'=>$row->image, 'link'=>$row->link) );
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        array_push($products, 'error');
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty Unclear. What you want to achieve over here

Comment: Why not just extend your sql statement. It would be faster and saves you some php code

Comment: @Philipp how would I do it in this case?

Comment: Show an example of the input i.e. `$products` Also show an example of the Query you would like your PHP code to generate. Edit your question, dont put this in a comment

Comment: If you want to select only products that match ALL checked properties, then you need to build a MySQL statement like "SELECT * FROM produkte WHERE `dog` = 1 AND `cat` = 1" using the foreach loop, then run that statement outside the loop to get all results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your SQL statement such that all checked values are equal to 1.

You can append a `" = 1 AND "` to each value then use them in your query.

```
<?php
$arr = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'];
$condition = join(' = 1 AND ', $arr) . ' = 1';
```

The output would be `"field1 = 1 AND field2 = 1 AND field3 = 1"`. You can then use `$condition` in your query.

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM produkte WHERE $condition")
```

UPDATE:

To cope with fieldname containing spaces you would need to wrap each fieldname with backticks so change this line

```
$condition = '`' . join('` = 1 AND `', $arr) . '` = 1';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is an amazing solution! But there is still just a little problem. In some of my column names there are spaces. As you see in my code I am using ` `$value` ` (with quote sign). How can I do this in your code? When I try ` `$conditional` ` it won't work.

Comment: You would have to wrap the fieldnames in backticks so change to this `$condition = '\`' . join('\` = 1 AND \`', $arr) . '\` = 1';`

Comment: @nopro Hope you dont mind me editing your answer. Seemed a better idea than writing one myself, as you really had answered the original question

Comment: Thank you very much! This is just exactly what I wanted!